# Running two RabbitMQ instances as Windows Service in single machine

Tags: rabbitmq

I have tried and successfully configured and run two rabbitmq instances as an application in Windows Server 2012. Following the tutorials below,

https://lazareski.com/multiple-rabbitmq-instances-on-1-machine/

https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html

but I have to repeat the above steps as soon as the server restarts or when my session is over.

How do I go about configuring and running two RabbitMQ Services in a single windows machine to permanently run them in background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to use the `.zip` distribution for Windows. Then, using two separate administrative accounts, set the required environment variables for two nodes in that account's environment. `RABBITMQ_SERVICENAME` will also have to be set and unique. Then, extract the `.zip` and run `rabbitmq-service.bat install` and `rabbitmq-service.bat run`.

The above is untested. Running multiple Erlang VMs on the same machine is not recommended as it can affect performance.